# deadlock chain sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

i'm newbie to sql managment... and i'm writing some .net 2.0 applications, one of these, is making many trouble with sql query, similar to many already done and working with problem (also without transactions...)
problems are starded when i've "splitted" the app on more cuncurrent machines (each one book his records/operations to work locally)
i've tried clustered index like read in some posts, looked with server profiler (and saved a screenshot) but it doesn't solve completely

someone could help me!? many thanks giacomo

one "shot" about one of these troubles.
where idOperazione is an operation id which rapresents each record
[image: deadlock]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell based on the information that you've provided, but a couple of questions:

1. Do you have an index on [ITCSTOKWEB].[dbo].[IdOperazione]? It needn't be the clustered index, but both operations involved in the deadlock are doing "update... where IdOperazione = 'some value'"; an index would help to make that operation more efficient.
2. What are the transaction isolation levels for each of the deadlock participants? You can find this information in the deadlock XML. I ask because I've seen deadlock problems when one or more of the participants sets their isolation level too high.